# шаблон не преобразуется к std::string а к std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>

Tags: c++

как сделать чтобы скомпилировался ?

```
template <typename T>
void func(const std::string& obj, const std::string& path,
          const std::string& iface, const std::string& property, T state)
{
    sdbusplus::asio::setProperty<T>(*conn, obj, path, iface, property, state,
                                    [](const boost::system::error_code&) {});
}

int main()
{

    std::string state = "state";
    func<std::string>("obj", "path", "iface", "property", state);

    return 0;
}
```

Ошибка

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘setProperty<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >(std::__shared_ptr_access<sdbusplus::asio::connection, __gnu_cxx::_S_atomic, false, false>::element_type&, const string&, const string&, const string&, const string&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&, func<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::<lambda(const boost::system::error_code&)>)’
   24 |     sdbusplus::asio::setProperty<T>(*conn, obj, path, iface, property, state,
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   25 |                                     [](const boost::system::error_code&) {});
```

Comment: Из кода не ясно, откуда берётся переменная conn, возможно в ней дело.

Answer (score -1):

std::string это и есть std::basic_string

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string

Comment: Почему именно это не является ответом: вопрос звучит как "как сделать чтобы скомпилировался ?", ваш ответ - "std::string это и есть std::basic_string". Ваш ответ никак не объясняет, как сделать, чтобы код скомпилировался.